# How to group objects when each object could go in multiple groups?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a `List<Student>` where each `Student` may have multiple hobbies:

```
public class StudentData {
    public static List<Student> getData() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Student(1, "a1", 1, Arrays.asList("cricket", "football", "basketball")),
            new Student(2, "a2", 1, Arrays.asList("chess", "football")),
            new Student(3, "a3", 2, Arrays.asList("running")),
            new Student(4, "a4", 2, Arrays.asList("throwball", "football")),
            new Student(5, "a5", 3, Arrays.asList("cricket", "basketball")),
            new Student(6, "a6", 4, Arrays.asList("cricket")), new Student(7, "a7", 5, Arrays.asList("basketball")),
            new Student(8, "a8", 6, Arrays.asList("football")),
            new Student(9, "a9", 8, Arrays.asList("tennis", "swimming")),
            new Student(10, "a10", 8, Arrays.asList("boxing", "running")),
            new Student(11, "a11", 9, Arrays.asList("cricket", "football")),
            new Student(12, "a12", 11, Arrays.asList("tennis", "shuttle")),
            new Student(13, "a13", 12, Arrays.asList("swimming"))
        );
    }
}
```

How to group the students based on hobbies? I tried this below code:

```
List<Student> data = StudentData.getData();
data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getHobbies().stream()));
```

It is not giving the right answer.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: cricket : student 1 ,student 5 ,student 6 obj..like this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically need a `Stream` that is made out of a `Pair` (I choose `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` here) that has the left part as a Hobby and right as the Student (could be the other way around, does not matter).

Later just group those based on `Hobby` (that is a String in your case).

```
data.stream()
    .flatMap(student -> student.getHobbies().stream().map(hobby -> new SimpleEntry<>(hobby, student)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
));
```

`Entry::getKey` being a method reference that gets the key, you could write it as a lambda expression too, if it makes more sense for you:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey())
```

Comment: thanks @Eugene.. just i rewirte the code. Map<String, List<Student>> collect5 = data.stream()
     .flatMap(x -> x.getHobbies().stream().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(y, x)))
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue,Collectors.toList())));