# How to group an object by 'name' using java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `DTO` with few attributes such as `id`, `name`, `desc`, etc.

It has getters and setters for all its attributes.

I get a `Page<MyDto>` from the service which I need to group the DTOs based on `name` attribute.

First, I convert the `Page<MyDto>` to `List<MyDto>` by using `page.getContent`.

I need to convert this `List` into a `Map<String, Object>` **(not `Map<String,String>`)** by grouping the same `names` using **`Java8`**.

I found some examples but they didn't resolve my problem.

How can I group the `MyDto` list into a Map?

where the keys are the names (**`String`**), and values would be an **`Array<MyDto>`** for each name.

For example:

```
If `List<MyDto>` is : 
[
{"id":1, "name":"albert", "desc":"science"},
{"id":2, "name":"george", "desc":"econ"},
{"id":3, "name":"christ", "desc":"math"},
{"id":4, "name":"george", "desc":"literature"} // george repeats twice
]
```

The output `Map` should be:

```
{

"george":

[
{"id":2, "name":"george", "desc":"econ"},
{"id":4, "name":"george", "desc":"literature"} 
],


"christ":

[
{"id":3, "name":"christ", "desc":"math"}
],


"albert":

[
{"id":1, "name":"albert", "desc":"science"}
]

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411257/java-8-group-by-string

Comment: `Map<String, List<MyDto>> map = dtos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyDto::getName));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and pass method reference to `MyDto::getName` method which will be used as the key for your map:

```
List<MyDto> dtos = ...
Map<String, List<MyDto>> map = dtos.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyDto::getName));
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Appreciate the help. Works as expected.